# Variable Query by Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, sql

I have created this code to filter the search by checkbox but I haven't find a final solution..!

This doesn't work when for example I click on 'All Colors' or 'All Brand'..

And not work when I recheck the checkbox because I haven't idea..!

This is a search to filter the results in eBay style, with combobox and much checkbox.. I want this to filter without the reload of the page..

This is the partial code..

```
function create_query(add){
    var query = "SELECT * FROM computers WHERE 1 = 1 "+add+" ORDER BY " + ($("#ordine option:selected").val()) + " LIMIT " + ($("#risultati option:selected").val());

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "static/cerca_prodotti.php",
        data: "query="+query,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(risposta){
            $("div#risultati").html(risposta);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Chiamata fallita!!!");
        }
    })
}

$( "[type=checkbox]" ).change(function() {
    text = $(this).parent().text();
    gruppo = this.getAttribute("name");
    if(this.checked) {

    }
    else {
        create_query('AND '+gruppo+' NOT LIKE "'+text+'"')
    }
});

$("#ordine").change(function() {
    create_query();
});

$("#risultati").change(function() {
    create_query();
});
```

Comment: Do you realize that this approach is awfully insecure?

Comment: Any particular reason you are using javascript instead of a simple form submission?

Comment: man, it's not at all secure, You are sending query from js which is insane.

Comment: I use javascript to not reload the page.. For user friendly..
I can take this secure by using the FILTER_INPUT(INPUT_GET of php..